# Valores do Choices estão sendo armazenados assim ['Cachorro', 'Gato', 'Pássaros']

Tags: python, django, django-2.0, django-queryset

tenho um sistema que terá a opção de escolha de 1 ou multiplas opções no mesmo campo. Mau problema é que preciso que meu campo dentro do model seja charfield e no forms seja MultipleChoiceField para poder validar multiplas escolhas.
Sei que poderia usar o filedmultiple no model e funcionaria, mas dai dari erro no django filter.
Preciso que como o modelo está agora, tanto forms quanto model, mas que ele passe para dentro do valores limpos e nao como esta passando agora, agora passa assim:['Cachorro', 'Gato', 'Pássaros']

models.py

```
PETN_CHOICES = (
    ('Cachorro','Cachorro'), ('Gato','Gato'), ('Pássaros', 'Pássaros'), ('Peixes','Peixes'), ('Reptéis','Reptéis'), ('Roedores','Roedores')
)
class Negocio(models.Model):
   pet_aceitos = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PETN_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
PETN_CHOICES = (
    ('Cachorro','Cachorro'), ('Gato','Gato'), ('Pássaros', 'Pássaros'), ('Peixes','Peixes'), ('Reptéis','Reptéis'), ('Roedores','Roedores')
)

class NegocioForm(UserCreationForm):
    pet_aceitos = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=PETN_CHOICES, )
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você tem um form recebendo ESCOLHAS FIXAS.
Dentro do seu MODEL *Negocio* o campo *pet_aceitos* não precisa ter o CHOICES. Você pode fazer esse "bloqueio" do usuário inserir apenas os dados que você deseja no form como já fez, e converter isso para SRT na view que está o form. Veja se ajuda :)